# Kubernetes only allow pull from specific private registry

Tags: kubernetes

I have a private registry and I want to allow worker nodes (running on Azure Kubernetes Services) to be able to pull images only from this registry.

Is there a way to allow worker nodes to only pull images from a specific private registry?

I would be surprised if the only way to achieve that is through complex firewall rules.

Comment: This has been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54464563/3438276 You just need an [Admission Controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Kubernetes does not have a feature which you are referring to.

You can read about [Pull an Image from a Private Registry](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/), which describes how to create a secret which holds the authorization token and how to use it.

On the other hand, I was able to find something in Docker called `Content trust`.

> Content trust allows operations with a remote Docker registry to enforce client-side signing and verification of image tags. Content trust provides the ability to use digital signatures for data sent to and received from remote Docker registries. These signatures allow client-side verification of the integrity and publisher of specific image tags.
>
> Currently, content trust is disabled by default. To enable it, set the `DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST` environment variable to `1`

Link to the documentation is available [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/trust/content_trust/), also you can read about it inside Docker blog [A secure supply chain for Kubernetes, Part 2](https://blog.docker.com/2018/03/secure-supply-chain-for-kubernetes-part-2/)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an private registry your docker tags of images inside it must have prefixed by the registry hostname. If not present, the command uses Docker’s public registry located at `registry-1.docker.io` by default. As example your registry hostname is docker.mycompany.net the tag of the image should be `docker.mycompany.net/{image-name}:{image-version}`. Documentation on docker tag can be found [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/).

So you just have to use that full tag of the image with the hostname prefix in your container specs as example to above scenario it should be like this.

```
containers:
   - name: my-container
     image: docker.mycompany.net/{image-name}:{image-version}
     ports:
      - containerPort: 80
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an admission controller policy for that. This depends on the admission controller you use. Here is how to [disallow repos in Gatekeeper](https://github.com/open-policy-agent/gatekeeper-library/blob/master/artifacthub/library/general/disallowedrepos/1.0.0/samples/repo-must-not-be-k8s-gcr-io/constraint.yaml) and here is how to do that in [Kyverno with Restrict Image Registries policy](https://kyverno.io/policies/best-practices/restrict-image-registries/restrict-image-registries/).